# composing single insert statement in slick 3

Tags: slick, slick-3.0

This is the case class representing the entire row:

`case class CustomerRow(id: Long, name: String, 20 other fields ...)`

I have a shape case class that only 'exposes' a subset of columns and it is used when user creates/updates a customer:

`case class CustomerForm(name: String, subset of all fields ...)`

I can use `CustomerForm` for updates. However I can't use it for inserts. There are some columns not in `CustomerForm` that are required (not null) and can only be provided by the server. What I do now is that I create `CustomerRow` from `CustomerForm`:

```
def form2row(form: CustomerForm, id: Long, serverOnlyValue: Long, etc...) = CustomerRow(
   id = id,
   serverOnlyColumn = serverOnlyValue,
   name = form.name.
   // and so on for 20 more tedious lines of code
)
```

and use it for insert.

Is there a way to compose insert in slick so I can remove that tedious `form2row` function?

Something like:

`(customers.map(formShape) += form) andAlsoOnTheSameRow .map(c => (c.id, c.serverOnlyColumn)) += (id, someValue)`

?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can do this like:

```
 case class Person(name: String, email: String, address: String, id: Option[Int] = None)

 case class NameAndAddress(name: String,address: String)

 class PersonTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Person](tag, "person") {
    val id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    val name = column[String]("name")
    val email = column[String]("email")
    val address = column[String]("address")
    //for partial insert 
    def nameWithAddress = (name, address)<>(NameAndAddress.tupled, NameAndAddress.unapply)

    def * = (name, email, address, id.?) <> (Person.tupled, Person.unapply)

    }

    val personTableQuery = TableQuery[PersonTable]

 // insert partial fields 
  personTableQuery.map(_.nameWithAddress) += NameAndAddress("abc", "xyz")
```

Make sure, You are aware of nullable fields they should be in form of Option[T] where T is filed type.In my example case, email should be Option[String] instead of String.